# Javascript can't see html elements fetched form a local file

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ms-word, fetch

I have an html file created by converting a Word file into html.
I copy-pasted the html code generated by Word into an html file that I added to my project (let's call it "local.html").

By using the fetch() function, I retrieved the text from the local.html file and added the data (formatted as text) to the innerHTML of a div within my index.html file.

The js code to do this is:

```
 fetch("./local.html")
  .then(response => {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(data => {
    document.getElementById("aDivInIndexhtml").innerHTML = data;
  });
```

The html tags generated by Word were recognized and correctly rendered by the browser (I am using Opera).

However, javascript does not see those elements (I can't do anything on them).

I thought this is because I added them to the innerHTML instead of appending the elements to the DOM.

I hence tried to append the div containing those elements (the "aDivInIndexhtml") to another div in my index.html. Same problem.
the code is:

```
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   newDiv.appendChild("aDivInIndexhtml");
```

What is most weird is that when I do:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("aDivInIndexhtml").children;
```

I get an HTMLCollection listing those elements.

Yet, if I try to access any element in the collection using for example:

```
document.getElementById("aDivInIndexhtml").children[0];`
```

or

```
 document.getElementById("aDivInIndexhtml").children.item(0);
```

I get an error telling that it is undefined.

If i do:

```
document.getElementById("aDivInIndexhtml").children.length
```

I get a 0 length collection although the same collection shows many elements when console.loged !

All the elements appear in the DOM of the browser and are rendered, but they almost do not exist for javascript or jquery.

I thought it would be the place of my code in the js file. I moved it to the end. Same problem.

Is it linked to the html/xml structure generated by Word? if so, how to fix it?

Comment: Can you add your actual code? My first guess is an async problem.

Comment: Converting from Word to HTML is quite a pain. I would try including the HTML of the new document that was created from Word. I wouldn't doubt if there is something wrapping the HTML.

Comment: For some reason, the html from Word needs to be replacable from time to time. It is not practical to add it directly in the index.htm if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

While printing this

```
document.getElementById("aDivInIndexhtml").children[0];
```

and this

```
 document.getElementById("aDivInIndexhtml").children.item(0);
```

You are getting undefined just because you div element aDivInIndexhtml does not have any children yet and it is an array, so that's why it is returning length 0 because it is empty. So to get it done, just append children in aDivInIndexhtml div like this:

**Change this**

```
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   newDiv.appendChild("aDivInIndexhtml");
```

**To This**

```
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   var aDivInIndexhtml = document.getElementById("aDivInIndexhtml");
   newDiv.appendChild(aDivInIndexhtml);
```

One more thing which is wrong here is you are passing string "aDivInIndexhtml" inside appendChild method, this is another reason you elements are not rendered in DOM, because appendChild method requires element not string.

Comment: The "aDivInIndexhtml" is a mistake in my post. In my code, I am referring the var representing the newDiv.

Your solution does not work. But I would have a question intriguing me in what you've said: how come the elements are not rendered in DOM while they are shown by the browser (I see the text) and even in the DOM tree in the devp tools?

I can see those elements as if they were hardcoded in the index.html body. It's js who can't access them.

Comment: In your comment you say that the "div element aDivInIndexhtml does not have any children yet and it is an array, so that's why it is returning length 0 because it is empty"
My question is: how aDivInIndexhtml would be empty without children while the browser and the DOM tree in the development tools are showing the elements fetched from the local.html. If these elements are rendered in the browser and appear in the DOM tree after being fetched, this should mean that the div container itself is not empty and the HTMLCollection of children of this div container should not be an empty array.

Comment: No if children array is empty that simply means your DOM is not ready and you are retreiving elements before that

Comment: It is empty even when the DOM tree in the devp tools are showing the elements? If so, what do you suggest in order to be able to work withe elements. I put my js code at the end of the js file and it still does not work. Will try again, but will appreciate your suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried wraping the code that will be applied to the fetched elements in an addeventlistener like this:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {// here is what to do with each fetched element})
it does not seem to work